# HTML / FLASK - Dynamic Table with Checkboxes per row

Tags: html, flask, html-table, jinja2

With Flask / HTML, I am dynamically populating a table of directory listings where I would like the user to have the option to select single or multiple directories via a checkbox, however when I check the box on any table row besides the first, only the first row's checkbox is being selected. I have ensured that the value of the checkboxes are independent, however I would like to have each row's checkbox to be unique to one another.

HTML:

```
<div id="select-form">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <h1>{{ directory.user_entered_path }}</h1>
    <table cellspacing="0" class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="head">Filename</td>
          <td class="head">Type</td>
          <td class="head">Size</td>
          <td class="head">Select</td>
        </tr>
        {% for file in dir_list %}
          <tr>
            <td name="name"> {{ file.file_name }}</td>
              <td> {{ file.file_type }} </td>
              <td> {{ file.file_size }}</td>
              <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="{{file}}">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">&nbsp;</label></td>
          </tr>
       {% endfor %}
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following:
To the end of your html, within the `<form></form>` I added a submit button for convenience, I don't know of another way to create a post request.

```html
  <form action="" method="post">
    <h1>{{ directory.user_entered_path }}</h1>
    <table cellspacing="0" class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="head">Filename</td>
          <td class="head">Type</td>
          <td class="head">Size</td>
          <td class="head">Select</td>
        </tr>

        {% for file in dir_list %}
          <tr>
            <td name="name"> {{ file.file_name }}</td>
              <td> {{ file.file_type }} </td>
              <td> {{ file.file_size }}</td>
              <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="check" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="{{file}}">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">&nbsp;</label></td>
          </tr>
       {% endfor %}
     </tbody>
   </table>
  <!-- added this button -->
  <button type="submit" name="submit-button" value="Submit">submit</button>
 </form>
```

Then I added this route to a flask `app.py`

```py
from flask import request, render_template

@app.route('/stack-dynamic-checkboxes', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def dynamic_checkboxes():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['submit-button'] == "Submit":

            for checkbox in request.form.getlist('check'):
                print(checkbox)


    def afile(x):
        return {'file_name':f'file {x}',
                'file_type':f'type {x}',
                'file_size':f'size {x}'}

    dir_list = [afile(x) for x in range(10)]
    directory = {'user_entered_path':'a path'}

    return render_template( 'testing/stack-dynamic-checkboxes.html',
                           directory=directory,
                           dir_list=dir_list )
```

When I run the app and navigate to the page with your html, select some checkboxes and press submit, I get information about the files printed to my console. They are all dictionaries in this format

```
{'file_name': 'file 0', 'file_type': 'type 0', 'file_size': 'size 0'}
```

I hope this was wat you were looking for.

I've been searching for a way to do this for a while. I'm glad you posted this question because I didn't understand the way I had to set up the HTML part correctly, so, thank you!

In the future, It would be nice to have a little bit more context, what your code looks like perhaps, as I'm uncertain whether this is what you were looking for